# Swiftmailer in Yii2 - Unable to send email

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I'm using basic Yii2 template and Swiftmailer to send email..

Here is my code for `config/web.php`:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport'=>'false',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

and my controller code is:

```
$fname = Yii::$app->request->post('fname');
        $email = Yii::$app->request->post('email');

        $industry = Yii::$app->request->post('industry');
        $info = Yii::$app->request->post('info');

        $mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com')
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setSubject('Test mail')
            ->setTextBody($info)
            ->send();
```

I'm getting email logs, but no email is being send...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your account less vulnerable, google has introduced this policy. As we login through our account without creating any app on Google, Google ask for our permission to ensure the security of our account.

Access below url to fix this problem and select "**Turn on**"
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

Attention you assign the result of the email `compose()...->send()` to $mail in this way you don't send the email but store the result in this variable.
try without assigment like:

```
    $industry = Yii::$app->request->post('industry');
    $info = Yii::$app->request->post('info');

    Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com')
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setSubject('Test mail')
        ->setTextBody($info)
        ->send();
```

Also attention to the

```
'useFileTransport'=>'false',
```

false i PHP value, I think you need use

```
 'useFileTransport'=>false,
```

whitout the `'`  character

Comment: I tried this too...but still not working.. I am getting email logs but no actual emails on the email id

Comment: still no succes... quick question... `username` in `web.php` and `setFrom()` in controller has to be same..? and do both them needs to be included...?  And I am passing my email address as hard coded...will be there be any issue if I do so..?

Comment: And do I have to enable my gmail account be accessed by 'less secure apps' ??

Comment: Please explain better what you mean by username in web.php and setFrom () in controller has to be same?

And a minor detail, I put before `setTo ()` `and then setFrom ()`

Comment: I mean to say that ` 'username'=>'email@gmail.com' ` in `web.php` and `setFrom('email@gmail.com')` has to be same...?And I am hard coding it...

Comment: In my case these value are the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77864/discussion-between-moid-mohd-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem and I used `port=>25` which solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**scaisEdge is right:**

You set `'useFileTransport'=>'false'`. Since `'false'` is a string, this will evaluate to `(bool) true`. You need to set it to `'useFileTransport' => false`.

**Further:**

If you're using something like AWS beanstalk environment variables which are always set as `string`, you want to evaluate it to `true` like this:

`'useFileTransport' => $_ENV['APP_STOPMAILER'] === "true" ? true : false,`