# send mail yii2 zoho

Tags: php, yii2

Im using swiftmailer in yii2 and zoho to send mail. Here is my config:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a uploads by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.zoho.com',
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'TLS',
            ],
        ],
```

and here is my function:

```
public function SendMail($from, $to,$subject, $body)
    {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setTextBody($body)
            ->send();
    }
```

It didn't work on server(integrate ssl) but it work find on my local, I've tried to debug but it return null and no exception. Can anyone have any idea to slove this stuff. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use yii `getLastTransaction()` function to check last transaction

```
public function SendMail($from, $to,$subject, $body)
    {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setTextBody($body)
            ->send();
    $status = Yii::$app->mailer->getLastTransaction();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($status);

}
```

you can check also there :- [Swiftmailer in Yii2 - Unable to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232720/swiftmailer-in-yii2-unable-to-send-email)

Answer (score 0):

Check your production server firewall. I have seen some shared hosting environments blocking smtp ports eg 587

to check if your 587 outgoing port is open type into console

```
telnet smtp.zoho.com 587
```

if you get a successful response eg:

```
Trying 65.154.166.201...
Connected to smtp.zoho.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.zohomail.com SMTP Server ready July 9, 2018 11:58:54 PM PDT
```

Then your firewall is ok and the problem must be somewhere else.